# Why ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'XXX', Where XXX is Itself

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.7, setuptools

I created a python package and hosted it in my own GitHub repository. When I pip install from the GitHub, I received the following error:

```
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'XXX'
```

where `XXX` was the name of the package I was trying to install. It just doesn't make sense to me. Can someone shed some light on this?

**Edit 1:**
I managed to find a permanent repository exhibiting this behavior. Try the following:

```
pip install https://github.com/rm-hull/luma.core/archive/master.zip
pip install https://github.com/rm-hull/luma.oled/archive/master.zip
```

In order to replicate the error, you **MUST** execute the pip commands in the order shown above (if you execute the second pip command first, then it won't generate the error). The last pip generated the following error:

```
...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'luma.oled'
```

I am using Python 3.7.9, pip 21.0.1, setuptools 54.1.1 running on Win10.

**Note:** There were long list of error messages in the place of `...`.

**Edit 2:**
Here is the full error when installing `luma.oled`:

```
Collecting https://github.com/rm-hull/luma.oled/archive/master.zip
  Using cached https://github.com/rm-hull/luma.oled/archive/master.zip
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\thonny\python.exe' 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphvzewynk'
       cwd: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-5w6wbo9g
  Complete output (48 lines):
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_xeaivwi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config.py", line 387, in _parse_attr
      return getattr(StaticModule(module_name), attr_name)
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_xeaivwi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config.py", line 25, in __init__
      with open(spec.origin) as strm:
  AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'origin'

  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 280, in <module>
      main()
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 263, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py", line 114, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      return hook(config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_xeaivwi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 150, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
      config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_xeaivwi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 130, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_xeaivwi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 145, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 7, in <module>
      setuptools.setup()
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_xeaivwi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\__init__.py", line 153, in setup
      return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\distutils\core.py", line 121, in setup
      dist.parse_config_files()
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_xeaivwi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\dist.py", line 708, in parse_config_files
      ignore_option_errors=ignore_option_errors)
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_xeaivwi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config.py", line 157, in parse_configuration
      meta.parse()
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_xeaivwi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config.py", line 463, in parse
      section_parser_method(section_options)
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_xeaivwi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config.py", line 436, in parse_section
      self[name] = value
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_xeaivwi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config.py", line 220, in __setitem__
      value = parser(value)
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_xeaivwi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config.py", line 552, in _parse_version
      version = self._parse_attr(value, self.package_dir)
    File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-_xeaivwi\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\config.py", line 390, in _parse_attr
      module = importlib.import_module(module_name)
    File "c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'luma.oled'
  ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://github.com/rm-hull/luma.oled/archive/master.zip. Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\thonny\python.exe' 'c:\users\user\appdata\local\programs\thonny\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' get_requires_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\tmphvzewynk' Check the logs for full command output.
```

Two errors triggered by `config.py` of  `setuptools`. But no error encountered if installed under Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster).

Comment: Hi @kaosad, could you please share more info?

Your repo, how are you storing your package, your configuration, ...

Comment: I am not sure if it is appropriate to put a link to my repo here because it would not be permanent. Please advise.

Comment: At least share your package configuration files, i.e. pyproject.toml, setup.py, etc.

Comment: Mmm.. I got this error under my env. I am using Python 3.7.9, pip 21.0.1, setuptools 54.1.1

Comment: Hmm.. Ok, it seems I spoke too soon about not being reproducible, sorry about that. But there seems to be other parts of the error. You just posted about the last line, but there's actually a "*AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'origin'*" at the top, **which seems to be the *main* exception**. It failed to build the wheel for one of the dependencies, so it could not install luma.oled successfully. It would be better if you can post the other parts of the error message and a reproducible example, that isn't from a github link. Probably related to a dependency or setup config.

Comment: @E_net4 could use more flags Can you please delete my question? If it remains closed, I don't see how it would help anyone out there.

Answer (score 1):

More details would be needed to answer precisely, but are you by any chance importing something from your own module in `setup.py`? As that is the installation process it can't access the code it's trying to install

Comment: I think this is good as comment, not as answer.

Comment: It's definitely an answer. Maybe not the right one for this asker, and it certainly doesn't cover all the possibilities, but still an answer. And clearly useful for any future visitors coming across this question.

Comment: I agree it's useful for future visitors, but it's still a comment. Future visitors can read the comments.

Comment: Is it the phrasing that's problematic? I'm saying "Remove import XXX from setup.py (if it's there)". It may not be applicable every time this issue comes up, but it may also very well solve the issue.